# Is it possible to reference constants in code from storyboard in Swift?

Tags: swift, storyboard

I have constants in my code, for example:

```
let cellHeight = 44
```

I don't know how to reference those constants from code in the storyboard. For example, in the storyboard, there are multiple section headers of a tableview:

[image]

I would like to control all of their heights with a constant, so if I decide to change the height, I don't have to change every storyboard value. I would like to replace those numbers with constant names.

I did some research, and couldn't find anything. I don't know if this is possible, but is it?

P.S. I know that I can just connect the UI to the code, and set the height in `viewDidLoad()`, but I want to use this way.

Comment: Your question seems a little unclear. Yes you have a constant value in your possible view controller, but what exactly are you trying to apply this constant on? A tableView, collectionView, etc... cell? Also which method are you referring to on your last sentence?

Comment: @Miket25 Sorry for being unclear. Basically, I have a bunch of custom section headers in a tableview, and each are supposed to be the same height. I want to have a constant to control their heights. When I said 'method' at the end, I meant like idea or way :)

Comment: I see. You seem to be heading in the general idea. You can call your own method within `viewDidLoad`, and inside set the frame of the view with you desired height. It'll be more helpful if you have some code to show.

Comment: Well, like I said in my question, I don't want to use the Swift code, and I would like to operate on the storyboard...

Comment: As @matt said, you need to rethink. First an app is *designed*, then it *processes code*. Design can be done in several ways - storyboards, xibs, plain code - and while there's overlap (think `@IBDesignable`), your question makes it seem you aren't clear on that. Here's the best you can do - (1) Subclass `UITableView` and set your specific code you want, then (2) add the table control in your storyboard and set it to your subclass, and (3) make sure you have these settings in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`. But I recommend that you first understand the difference between design- and run-time.

Comment: Why are people downvoting? I understand that my question is a little bit unclear, and I have clarified the question in the comments. Is there any other reason?

Comment: @dfd Is my question worded a bit clearer now with pictures?

Comment: @Miket25 Is my question worded a bit clearer now with pictures?

Comment: @matt Is my question worded a bit clearer now with pictures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple way, because a storyboard is not code — there is nothing there that can "see" your variable `cellHeight`.

However, what you are asking to do is something you should not *want* to do. If you have sizes that need to be adjusted depending on the screen size, or views that need to be adjusted when some other view changes, that is what auto layout is for.

Otherwise, you will just have to write code that changes all the things you want changed when you want them changed.